# What's the difference between やく and くすり?

Tags: word-choice, nouns

They both mean medicine. But when to use which?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33830/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/2863/9831

Comment: 薬{やく} by itself or at the end of a word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this dictionary entry](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E8%96%AC) 薬{くすり} means medicine, but 薬{やく} is a slang word for drugs/narcotics.